# Undefined index: username

Tags: php, mysql

I checked other questions of " Undefined index: username". and none of these questions were properly answered. So I decide to make my own question.

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in D:\\xampp\htdocs\project\test.php on line 19
```

Below is the code which shows the above error:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$sessionQuery = "SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$sessionMysqlQuery = mysql_query($sessionQuery);
if(mysql_num_rows($sessionMysqlQuery) === 0){
    header('Location: ./page.php');
}
```

Comment: Show line `19` please.

Comment: You should have something like `foo['username']` in your code...

Comment: What a coincidence that my username is `admin' --` and I can log in as admin without even knowing the password. Thanks for allowing SQL injection and hacking! You also use cleartext passwords and use deprecated DB functions. Please tell me the URL after you've uploaded this to the internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although we are giving guesses here since you are probably missing the code which gives the `notice`, you are probably trying to reference the `username` in code similar to:

```
$username = $row['username'];
```

and since in your `SQL` query you are only returning the `id` of the `admin` by

> SELECT id FROM ...

the returned array does not have the `username` index.

It's either that or although you are getting an empty result, inside the included page:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sessionMysqlQuery) === 0){
    header('Location: ./page.php');
}
```

you are still trying to access the `username` index of the result set which means you code's logic is broken or you would want to check for `=== 1` before including whatever is included in `page.php`.